# Wordpress non registered comments slow to post / tracing php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

I bought a cheap vps and installed apache 2.2, MySQL and wordpress. Overall it runs pretty well with decent page load times. If I am logged in as admin I can make post comments and they save very quickly however as a non registered / anonymous user when I try to save a comment it takes 45 - 60 seconds to save.

I have tried using fast cgi and mod_php but the results are similar.

This is an out of the box install with no plugins or non stock themes enabled.

Is there a way to trace the calls made during the post process? I have tried setting wp debug but that doesn't provide much logging.

Comment: i think the reason for the slowness is wordpress has a built in mechanism for checking for spam comments, so from anonymous users i think the spam check is triggering

Comment: Is that out of the box behavior or do you have to enable the Akismet plugin? I don't have that plugin enabled.